# Read binary file in C skip byte of 0

Tags: c

When i read a binary file the program skip the byte who are equal to 0.
There is my program in C :

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
        FILE * input_file = fopen("binary.bin", "rb");
        uint32_t b = 0 ;
        fread(&b, sizeof(uint32_t) , 1 , input_file);

        printf("----- Here are the data stored in the file -----\n");
        printf("First uint_32 : %d\n", b);
        printf("------------------------------------------------\n");

    return 0;
}
```

The output :

```
----- Here are the data stored in the file ----- 
First uint_32 : 16777216 
------------------------------------------------
```

The binary file :

```
xxd -b binary.bin
00000000: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000000 00000000  ......
00000006: 00000000 00110010 00000000 00000000 00000000 01100100  .2...d
0000000c: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00010100 00000000 00000000  ......
00000012: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 01011001 00110000  ....Y0
```

Why the output is not 1 ?

Comment: Little Endian : Higher MSB at higher Memory Address. [LittleEndian](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ed/Little-Endian.svg/200px-Little-Endian.svg.png)

Comment: fread return 1 and it would be 1 in the binary file if we take the 32 first bits no?

Comment: How are you going to know if a byte is zero and needs to be skipped if you don't read it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got `16777216` as an output.

Let's see its binary representation

```
00000001000000000000000000000000
```

That's due to how data is written in the memory depending on the architecture of the system.

That's [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of the system. You should read about `little-endian` and `big-endian`

Comment: It may or may not be relevant that the `ntohl()` function, if available in the OP's environment, converts big-endian (a.k.a. "network byte order") 32-bit representation to native 32-bit representation, whatever the latter happens to be.

Comment: @JohnBollinger You're right. Corrected it.